# Max/min value of two dimensional table

Tags: java

I have to make a table in java and than using method fin max min value. Here is my code, i dont know how to input a method who wil return me max/min value.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Max {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader   (System.in));

    System.out.print("Input a numbers of rows: ");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

    System.out.print("Input a numbers of a columns: ");
    int b = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

    int [][] tab = new int [a][b];

    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++){
            tab[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*10001);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(tab[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: by writing it and keeping track of the min and max value while looping over the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {

                if (tab[i][j] < min) {
                    min = tab[i][j];
                }
                if (tab[i][j] > max) {
                    max = tab[i][j];
                }
            }

        }
System.out.println("min:" + min + ", max:" + max);
```

Comment: In the future you should add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either when you are setting up the array

```
int max = 0;
for (int i =0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
        int val = Math.random(100001);
        if (val > max) {
            max = val;
        }
    }
}
```

or after you have setup the array

```
int max = 0;
for (int i =0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
        if (tab[i][j] > max) {
            max = tab[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```